# adding loader at login button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a login button which when clicked should show a loader. Here's what I have tried.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    loader=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]      initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    loader.frame = CGRectMake(13, 3, 80, 60);
    [loader startAnimating];
    loader.tag = 100;
    [loadingView addSubview:loader];
    UILabel* lblLoading = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(62, 15, 150, 30)];
    lblLoading.text = @"Signing in...";
    lblLoading.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblLoading.font = [UIFont fontWithName:lblLoading.font.fontName size:15];
    lblLoading.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [loadingView addSubview:lblLoading];
     [self.view addSubview:loadingView];
    loadingView.hidden = YES;
  }
-(void)signinBtnPressed {
     loadingView.hidden = NO;
     //api code
}
```

But there is no loader loaded when utton is clicked.It shows after some time when the API is called
Can anyone tell me how to show the loader as soon as button is clicked or any other alternative.

Comment: Heard of MBProgressHUD ?? Why to reinvent the wheel when you have tubeless tires in market ?? :o

Comment: You cannot set `frame` to `UIActivityIndicatorView`, try to set `center`.

Comment: You've lost `[super viewDidLoad]` call.

Comment: @timur no it is there, i haven't pasted it here.

Answer (score 2):

I have an example of **NVActivityIndicatorView**. Please have a look.

**NSObject class:**

```
import UIKit
import NVActivityIndicatorView
        class Helper: NSObject
        {

          class func createLoaderView(_ view : UIView) -> NVActivityIndicatorView
            {
                var ViewFrame : CGRect!

                ViewFrame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60 , height: 60)
                let center = CGPoint(x: (view.frame).midX, y: (view.frame).midY)

                 let activityIndicatorView =  NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: ViewFrame, type: .ballSpinFadeLoader , color: UIColor(red: 200/255, green: 58/255, blue: 60/255, alpha:1.0), padding: CGFloat(0))

                activityIndicatorView.center = center

                activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

                return activityIndicatorView
            }

            class func removeLoaderView(_ activityIndicatorView : NVActivityIndicatorView)
            {
                activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
            }

           class func addBlurView(_ inView : UIView) -> UIVisualEffectView
           {
               let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
               let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

               //always fill the view
               blurEffectView.frame = inView.bounds
                blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
                blurEffectView.alpha = 0.5

                return blurEffectView
          }
}
```

In view controller where you want to show the loader call method of Helper class. Like:

```
    import UIKit
    import NVActivityIndicatorView

    class ViewController: UIViewController,NVActivityIndicatorViewable
    {
        var activityIndicatorView : NVActivityIndicatorView!
        var blurEffectView : UIVisualEffectView!

       override func viewDidLoad() 
       {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        func showProgressView()
        {
            activityIndicatorView =      Helper.createLoaderView(self.navigationController!.view)
            blurEffectView = Helper.addBlurView((self.navigationController?.view)!)
            self.navigationController!.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
            self.navigationController!.view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
        }

        func hideProgressView()
        {
            Helper.removeLoaderView(activityIndicatorView)
            blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
      }
   }
```

**Note:** In order to show loader you have to call "showProgressView". Similarly to hide loader call hide method. To import ** NVActivityIndicatorView**  you have to install pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine, you should post all code related to this view. I've created playground and looks like it's OK:

[image]

At the same time, I see no loadingView creation and `[super viewDidLoad]` call.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you have not allocate `loadingView`
just allocate it and set frame or center like this way

```
loadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
loadingView.center = self.view.center;
```

Answer (score 0):

apurv, there is so many readymade external lib.s are available. But if you want your own customization, then can try this:

In `AppDelegate`

```
-(void)showActivityIndicatorWithTitle:(NSString *)title andUserInteraction:(BOOL)interaction
{
    _hudView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.window.frame.size.width/2)-60, (self.window.frame.size.height/2)-60, 120, 120)];
    _hudView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _hudView.alpha = 0.85f;
    _hudView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _hudView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

    self.acivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.acivityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, self.acivityIndicator.bounds.size.width, self.acivityIndicator.bounds.size.height);
    [_hudView addSubview:self.acivityIndicator];
    [self.acivityIndicator startAnimating];

    _captionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 80, 110, 40)];
    _captionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _captionLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _captionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    _captionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    _captionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    _captionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _captionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    _captionLabel.text = title;
    [_hudView addSubview:_captionLabel];

    self.window.userInteractionEnabled = interaction;

    [self.window addSubview:_hudView];
}

-(void)removeIndicator
{
    self.window.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.acivityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    [_captionLabel removeFromSuperview];
    [_hudView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

set the property of *_hudView, self.acivityIndicator and _captionLabel* in `AppDelegate.h` file and add these two methods in .h file also.

use these two methods to add and remove the loader throughout the project when you need. Don't forget to instantiate the app delegate.

Thanks